# How can I add my treat node in multiple places throughout the game?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to have about 15 treats and I just want to change the x position of these treats. I don't want to copy and paste this code 15 times, so how can I go about doing this?

```
func createTreatNode() {
    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Treat")
    let q1 = atlas.textureNamed("treat1.png")
    let q2 = atlas.textureNamed("treat2.png")
    let q3 = atlas.textureNamed("treat3.png")
    let treatAnimation = [q1, q2, q3]
    let treat = SKSpriteNode(texture: q1)
    treat.position = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 150)
    print("treat position \(treat.position)")
    treat.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 50)
    treat.name = "Treat"
    let animate = SKAction.animate(with: treatAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(animate)
    treat.run(repeatAction)
    let body = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: treat.size)
    body.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    body.affectedByGravity = false
    body.collisionBitMask = 0x7FFFFFFF
    body.contactTestBitMask = 0x80000000
    treat.physicsBody = body
    addChild(treat)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding a parameter to your `createTreatNode()` function. Then change `treat.position = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 150)` to `treat.position = CGPoint(x: atXCoordinate, y: 150)` like this:

```
func createTreatNode(atXCoordinate: Int) {
    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Treat")
    let q1 = atlas.textureNamed("treat1.png")
    let q2 = atlas.textureNamed("treat2.png")
    let q3 = atlas.textureNamed("treat3.png")
    let treatAnimation = [q1, q2, q3]
    let treat = SKSpriteNode(texture: q1)
    treat.position = CGPoint(x: atXCoordinate, y: 150)
    print("treat position \(treat.position)")
    treat.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 50)
    treat.name = "Treat"
    let animate = SKAction.animate(with: treatAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(animate)
    treat.run(repeatAction)
    let body = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: treat.size)
    body.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    body.affectedByGravity = false
    body.collisionBitMask = 0x7FFFFFFF
    body.contactTestBitMask = 0x80000000
    treat.physicsBody = body
    addChild(treat)
}
```

This way you can call `createTreatNode(atXCoordinate:)` 15 times with different x coordinates and it will add treat child nodes to the current scene at the x coordinates you passed to it.